# Deploymennt of grpc jar on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grpc, grpc-java

I am building Grpc application to accept requests and respond with response. So for deployment want to check, if it could be deployed on Tomcat 9.0.44.

I tried it out but was not successfull, so just want to check feasibility of the deployment options for Grpc Java Server Application.

Thanks,
Atul.

Comment: Please explain what happened, not just "not successful."

Comment: I get following message even when i have configure the user in tomcat_users.xml : 403: You are not authorized to view this page.
By default the Manager is only accessible from a browser running on the same machine as Tomcat. 
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui"/>
My current configuration is, and i am able to login using same id:
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="pass" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>